# send a file using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

I have a form that contains text fields & 2 file upload fields. The form datashould be sent to an email address using ajax. However, with my code only the text fields are being sent, while the files are being omitted.

In order to solve this problem, I have used "[valums-file-uploader](http://github.com/valums/file-uploader)", to upload the files to directory on the server in an attempt to get the files links and send them along with the form(instead of attaching them to the email, which I initially tried hard to achieve).

The problem now is: the files are being uploaded to a specified directory on the server, but I am not able to send their links through an email.

Here is my code:
"demo.htm"

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link href="fileuploader.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
    <style>     
        body {font-size:13px; font-family:arial, sans-serif; width:700px; margin:100px auto;}

    </style>    
</head>
<body>      




<p><a href="http://github.com/valums/file-uploader">Back to project page</a></p>


<p>To upload a file, click on the button below. Drag-and-drop is supported in FF, Chrome.</p>
<p>Progress-bar is supported in FF3.6+, Chrome6+, Safari4+</p>

<div id="file-uploader-demo1">      
    <noscript>          
        <p>Please enable JavaScript to use file uploader.</p>
        <!-- or put a simple form for upload here -->
    </noscript>         
</div>
<div id="uploaderFile"></div> 

<script src="fileuploader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>        
    function createUploader(){            
        var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
            element: document.getElementById('file-uploader-demo1'),
            action: 'php.php',
            debug: true,
            onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON){
                            alert(responseJSON["filename"]);
                        }
        });
    }

    // in your app create uploader as soon as the DOM is ready
    // don't wait for the window to load  
    window.onload = createUploader;     
</script>    
</body>
</html>
```

"php.php"

```
<?php

/**
 * Handle file uploads via XMLHttpRequest
 */

class qqUploadedFileXhr {

/**
 * Save the file to the specified path
 * @return boolean TRUE on success
 */

function save($path) {    
    $input = fopen("php://input", "r");
    $temp = tmpfile();
    $realSize = stream_copy_to_stream($input, $temp);
    fclose($input);

    if ($realSize != $this->getSize()){            
        return false;
    }

    $target = fopen($path, "w");        
    fseek($temp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    stream_copy_to_stream($temp, $target);
    fclose($target);

    return true;
}
function getName() {
    return $_GET['qqfile'];
}
function getSize() {
    if (isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_LENGTH"])){
        return (int)$_SERVER["CONTENT_LENGTH"];            
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Getting content length is not supported.');
    }      
}   
}


/**
 * Handle file uploads via regular form post (uses the $_FILES array)
 */

class qqUploadedFileForm {  
/**
 * Save the file to the specified path
 * @return boolean TRUE on success
 */

function save($path) {
    if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['qqfile']['tmp_name'], $path)){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
function getName() {
    return $_FILES['qqfile']['name'];
}
function getSize() {
    return $_FILES['qqfile']['size'];
}
}

class qqFileUploader {
    private $allowedExtensions = array();
    private $sizeLimit = 10485760;
    private $file;

function __construct(array $allowedExtensions = array(), $sizeLimit = 10485760){        
    $allowedExtensions = array_map("strtolower", $allowedExtensions);

    $this->allowedExtensions = $allowedExtensions;        
    $this->sizeLimit = $sizeLimit;

    //$this->checkServerSettings();    


    if (isset($_GET['qqfile'])) {
        $this->file = new qqUploadedFileXhr();
    } elseif (isset($_FILES['qqfile'])) {
        $this->file = new qqUploadedFileForm();
    } else {
        $this->file = false; 
    }
}

private function checkServerSettings(){        
    $postSize = $this->toBytes(ini_get('post_max_size'));
    $uploadSize = $this->toBytes(ini_get('upload_max_filesize'));        

    if ($postSize < $this->sizeLimit || $uploadSize < $this->sizeLimit){
        $size = max(1, $this->sizeLimit / 1024 / 1024) . 'M';             
        die("{'error':'increase post_max_size and upload_max_filesize to $size'}");    
    }        
}

private function toBytes($str){
    $val = trim($str);
    $last = strtolower($str[strlen($str)-1]);
    switch($last) {
        case 'g': $val *= 1024;
        case 'm': $val *= 1024;
        case 'k': $val *= 1024;        
    }
    return $val;
}


/**
 * Returns array('success'=>true) or array('error'=>'error message')
 */

function handleUpload($uploadDirectory, $replaceOldFile = FALSE){
    if (!is_writable($uploadDirectory)){
        return array('error' => "Server error. Upload directory isn't writable.");
    }

    if (!$this->file){
        return array('error' => 'No files were uploaded.');
    }

    $size = $this->file->getSize();

    if ($size == 0) {
        return array('error' => 'File is empty');
    }

    if ($size > $this->sizeLimit) {
        return array('error' => 'File is too large');
    }

    $pathinfo = pathinfo($this->file->getName());
    $filename = $pathinfo['filename'];
    //$filename = md5(uniqid());
    $ext = $pathinfo['extension'];

    if($this->allowedExtensions && !in_array(strtolower($ext), $this->allowedExtensions)){
        $these = implode(', ', $this->allowedExtensions);
        return array('error' => 'File has an invalid extension, it should be one of '. $these . '.');
    }

    if(!$replaceOldFile){
        /// don't overwrite previous files that were uploaded
        while (file_exists($uploadDirectory . $filename . '.' . $ext)) {

            $filename .= '_'.rand(10, 999);
        }
    }

    if ($this->file->save($uploadDirectory . $filename . '.' . $ext)){

        //return array('success'=>true);

        return array('success'=>true, 'filename'=>$uploadDirectory . $filename . '.' . $ext);
        mail('username@domain.com', 'File Link', $uploadDirectory . $filename . '.' . $ext, 'username@domain.com');
    } else {
        return array('error'=> 'Could not save uploaded file.' .
            'The upload was cancelled, or server error encountered');
    }        
}    
}

// list of valid extensions, ex. array("jpeg", "xml", "bmp")

$allowedExtensions = array();

// max file size in bytes

$sizeLimit = 10 * 1024 * 1024;

$uploader = new qqFileUploader($allowedExtensions, $sizeLimit);
$result = $uploader->handleUpload('uploads/');

// to pass data through iframe you will need to encode all html tags

echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($result), ENT_NOQUOTES);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `mail` *after* you return a value from `handleUpload`.  Any code following a `return` like this is unreachable and will not be executed.